# Combining two RewriteRules is overriding the first

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to apply two RewriteRules at the same time. They both work exactly as intended independently (when the other is commented out), but when placed in the `.htaccess` file together, only the first rule works.

How can I use these together?

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect everything to this file
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]

# Rewrite location of the storage files making them public
RewriteRule ^storage/(.*)$ app/files/public/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Change the order? Your first rule applies to _all_ requests, and then you got the `L` flag in there to say, “done for this round”. So of course the second rule never gets to apply. The rule of thumb with rewriting is - always go in order from more specific, to less specific.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the suggestion, but changing the order does not allow both rules to coexist.

Comment: Did you put the `L` flag on the - now - first rule, so that the second one doesn’t rewrite _everything_ to the index.php in the public folder afterwards again?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your explanation. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from @CBroe, here is the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite location of the storage files making them public
RewriteRule ^storage/(.*)$ app/files/public/$1 [QSA,L]

# Redirect everything to this file
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA]
```